# How to compare values of mathematic functions in a python function (def)

Tags: python, function, boolean, compare

I am writting a code to compare mathematic functions and say which one of them has the biggest value for given x and y

```
import math

def r(x,y):
  r = 3 * math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)
  return r

def b(x,y):
  b = 2 * math.pow(x, 2) + 5 * math.pow(y, 2)
  return b

def c(x,y):
  c = -100 * x + math.pow(y, 3)
  return c

def compare():
  x = float(input("Type the value of x: "))
  y = float(input("Type the value of y: "))
  r(x,y)
  b(x,y)
  c(x,y)

  if r > b and c:
    print("r is the biggest.")
    return
  elif b > r and c:
    print("b is the biggest.")
    return
  elif c > b and r:
    print("c is the biggest.")
    return

compare()
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'

Answer (score 1):

You must assign the result of each function to a variable. Try the following:

```
import math

def r(x,y):
  r = 3 * math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)
  return r

def b(x,y):
  b = 2 * math.pow(x, 2) + 5 * math.pow(y, 2)
  return b

def c(x,y):
  c = -100 * x + math.pow(y, 3)
  return c

def compare():
  x = float(input("Type the value of x: "))
  y = float(input("Type the value of y: "))
  R=r(x,y)
  B=b(x,y)
  C=c(x,y)

  if R > B and R>C:
    print("r is the biggest.")
    return
  elif B > R and B>C:
    print("b is the biggest.")
    return
  elif C > B and C>R:
    print("c is the biggest.")
    return

compare()
```

Comment: Your code carries over a bug from OP involving comparisons and `and`.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs here:

- You need to compare the actual results of the function, not the function object itself.
- You can't compare one numerical value to the `and` of two other values; what you're actually testing for in that case is a single comparison plus whether the other value is non-zero!

I'd use the `max` function to get the largest value rather than building a complicated chain of conditionals to do the same thing.  That way if you add another function it's easy to just add it to the list:

```
import math

def r(x, y):
    return 3 * math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)

def b(x, y):
    return 2 * math.pow(x, 2) + 5 * math.pow(y, 2)

def c(x, y):
    return -100 * x + math.pow(y, 3)

def compare():
    functions = [r, b, c]  # maybe this could be a parameter?
    x = float(input("Type the value of x: "))
    y = float(input("Type the value of y: "))

    result, func_name = max((f(x, y), f.__name__) for f in functions)
    print(f"{func_name} is the biggest.")

compare()
```

```
Type the value of x: 1
Type the value of y: 2
b is the biggest.

Type the value of x: 0
Type the value of y: 0
r is the biggest.

Type the value of x: -1
Type the value of y: -2
c is the biggest.
```